# Pass a member function as Compare operator for C++ standard library algorithm

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-library

In my code I have now something like

```
    Foo bar;
    std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator minElement =
      std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                       std::end(mySet),
                       [&bar](Foo const &lhs, Foo const &rhs) {
                         return bar.myWeakLessOperator(lhs, rhs);
                       });
```

I wonder wether it exists a way to simplify it by passing directly the member function `myWeakLessOperator` (that is not static) instead of writing a lambda function just to make to call.

I would like to obtain something like

```
    Foo bar;
    std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator minElement =
      std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                       std::end(mySet),
                       /* something that rely to */ bar.myWeakLessOperator);
```

Any idea if it possible and how to do it ?

Comment: with `std::bind(&Foo::myWeakLessOperator, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)` you can get away with `bar`, but why not just make a static version ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki in that case OP may just remove the first parameter from `myWeakLessOperator` altogether since it's just `this` duplicated.

Comment: @Azias could you elaborate on what `myWeakLessOperator` does, why is it a member function when it seems to compare two unrelated objects?

Comment: I cannot have a static version because the result of myWeakLessOperator will depend on the object.
Actually my operator compares two objects against their distance to a main object (`myWeakLessOperator`  could be renamed `ClosestThan`). `bar`is the main object, and my final goal with std::min_element is to find the element from `mySet' that is the closest to `bar`

Comment: Then my answer is not a solution unfortunately, what you want is basically a bound member function. I had a need for this a couple days ago, but couldn't find anything, so I wrote my own. I'm trying to recreate it just now.

Comment: @Pezo Thanks for you time anyway. Actually I think the good solution in my situation would actually to have a member function `FindClosest` in `Foo` that will do the job such that the complexity is hidden for the user of `Foo`. But I have another problem with that and I will probably create another thread for that.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, might have what you're looking for.

Comment: If you are simply looking to make the code easier to read I think a good option here is to `auto comp = [&bar](Foo const &lhs, Foo const &rhs) { return bar.myWeakLessOperator(lhs, rhs); };` and then pass in `comp` in your call.

Comment: you need have `bool operator()(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)` inside `Foo` after this you can simply pass instance of `Foo` - `std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                       std::end(mySet), bar)`

Comment: @RbMm that's not a good idea unless calling a `Foo` really does mean _calculate the distance_ in OP's domain. Also, you can't have any other comparison this way.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to have a function object that represents a member function bound to a particular receiver. Unfortunately, there's nothing I could find in the standard or Boost that does that.

What you can do is write your own fairly easily.

```
template <typename R, typename T>
struct member_function_binder {
    T *receiver;
    R T::*pmf;

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return (receiver->*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename R, typename T>
auto bind_member_function(R T::*pmf, T &receiver) {
    return member_function_binder<R, T>{&receiver, pmf};
}
```

Have a look at the [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5J-S2m), I think this might be what you want.

---

Even more concise, you don't need to have a separate class `member_function_binder` if you return a lambda from `bind_member_function` like so:

```
template <typename R, typename T>
auto bind_member_function(R T::*pmf, T &receiver) {
    return [pmf, &receiver](auto&&... args) {
        return (receiver.*pmf)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WXWxnl)

---

Solution to pass a unary member function like `Foo::compareTo(const Foo &rhs)`, not what OP asked:

What you want is [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn); it's a wrapper that makes a member function pointer into a function object. You would use it like this:

```
auto min = std::min_element(
        begin(mySet), end(mySet), std::mem_fn(&Foo::myWeakLessOperator));
```

Comment: `myWeakLessOperator` is a 2-parameter member function

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I just noticed that too, that doesn't seem very sensible though.

Comment: I don't think this would work, as you need 3 parameters to invoke the wrapper properly in this example.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to use a struct that satisfies [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) inside Foo:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    struct WeakLessOperator
    {
        bool operator()(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
        {
            // implementation - take care of meeting requirements of Compare
            return true;
        }
    };
    WeakLessOperator myWeakLessOperator;
};

Foo bar;

auto minElement =
    std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                     std::end(mySet),
                     bar.myWeakLessOperator);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `std::bind`, or some other [wrapper](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/memfun.hpp).

EXAMPLE:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
Foo bar;
std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator minElement =
  std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                   std::end(mySet),
                   std::bind(&Foo::myWeakLessOperator, bar, _1, _2));
```

OR

```
Foo bar;
std::unordered_set<Foo>::iterator minElement =
  std::min_element(std::begin(mySet),
                   std::end(mySet),
                   gnr::memfun<MEMFUN(Foo::myWeakLessOperator)>(bar));
```

Comment: Can you give an example, I am not used to `std::bind` and co, I cannot see how to use it.

Comment: Lambda is superior to everything, though, faster, takes up less space, ...

Comment: I have tried with this example and it effectively does the job. thanks.

Comment: You should know that `std::bind` is a lambda precursor. Effectively, the lambda replaces it and is superior.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to what you want is maybe

```
auto minElement =
  std::min_element(
            std::begin(mySet),
            std::end(mySet),
            mem_fun_functor(&Foo::myWeakLessOperator) 
  );
```

There is `std::mem_fun` (deprecated in c++11) and `std::mem_fn` both wrap a member function pointer, though both take a instance as parameter to invoke the member function. If you want a functor that wraps the object also, i think you need to write your own:

```
auto mem_fun_functor = 
    [&bar](decltype(&Foo::myWeakLessOperator) f){
        return [f,&bar](const Foo& a,const Foo& b) {
                  return (bar.*f)(a,b); 
               };
};
```

However, given that none of the answers is really much shorter or leading to cleaner code, I would consider to just use your first version with the lambda (unless you maybe have many different member functions that you want to use as comparator).

What do you actually mean by "simplifying" ? You do need to specify the object you want to call the member function on, you need to specify how you want to forward the parameters. Thats basically all the lambda does.

Defering all this to a functor as for example above makes your code more complicated rather than simpler. In your first snippet anybody familiar with standard algorithms can look at that few lines of code and fully understand what is going on.

Eventually it is a matter of style, and what you consider as readable, but being able to declare stuff in the most narrowest scope is one big advantage of using lambdas.

Comment: Correction: `std::mem_fun` was deprecated long ago and removed in C++17, you shouldn't use that. `std::mem_fn` is the way to go, it takes both references and pointers (raw or smart) as receivers.

Comment: I really like your idea of returning a lambda, I never think of that.

Comment: @Pezo my favourite is mjdmochowski's answer, though I really think just writing the lambda directly in the algorithm call is the most clean way. Its a bit of typing, but I prever to have everything in the most narrow scope. Whether there are reasons to pull something to a higher scope isnt really clear from the question

Comment: I don't particularly like that solution since it'll waste space, because you need a reference/pointer to the containing object in the operator object (so it can access members).